# Compile to apk from Linux Terminal

Tags: android, linux, build.gradle, gradlew, auto-compile

I want to compile my code to apk from Linux Terminal, I tried to run the gradlew which is in the app's file but stack at the 52% of the progress.
I have installed the gradle, (sudoku apt-get install gradle)
I have installed the sdk tools.
If I have not mentioned something which is important to know for the problem, ask me.

Comment: `./gradlew clean build` should be all you need. (provided Java and Android SDK is installed). Make sure to wait long enough, a lot of files will be downloaded during the process.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project directory and run

> on Windows

```
gradlew
```

> on Mac or Linux

```
./gradlew
```

Check it out [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html).